# NoMethodError in Blog::PostsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, rails-routing

Note: Rails newb here.

So, I recently created a Rails app with `mongoid` gem for use of MongoDB. I have a namespace route of `:blog` with a nest of resource of `posts`

Routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :blog do
    resources :posts
  end
end
```

The error comes from app/controllers/blog/posts_controller.rb:

```
Class Blog::PostsController < ApplicationController
  def create
   @post = Post.new(post_params)

  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'new'
  end
 end

 private
 def post_params
 params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
 end
end
```

I also have a 'post' model that comes with a title and body:

```
Class Post
 include Mongoid::Document
 field :title, type: String
 field :body, type: String
end
```

In new.html.erb:

```
<h1>Rails Sample Blog</h1>

<%= form_for @post, url: blog_post_path do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.label :title %><%= f.text_field :title %></div>
  <div><%= f.label :body %><%= f.text_area :body %></div>
<% end %>
```

Is there something I left out that I didn't catch? **It's slowly haunting me.**

Edit: See this Git repo: https://github.com/hackathons-com/Rails-MongoDB-Devise-test

Edit 2:

```
undefined method `post_url' for #<Blog::PostsController:0x007f3d19105ee8>
```

Comment: Class should be lowercase (capital Class is actually the name of a class itself). Not sure if that'll fix it, but definitely a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 def create

 @blog = Blog.find(params[:blog_id])

 @post= @blog.posts.build(post_params)
```

(This assumes that you already added a column of `blog_id` and have your associations correct, although looking at your model it looks like you may have missing associations?)

Comment: My routes are defined with as namespace `/blog/post/:id` but I could do that as well if I define the route something like `resources :blog do resources :posts end`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 app/controllers/blog/post_controller.rb:
```

Shouldn't this be posts_controller.rb?

Also

```
Class Blog::PostController < ApplicationController
```

should be

```
Class Blog::PostsController < ApplicationController
```

Comment: Yeah, my bad. But that is not the case.

Comment: My apologies, I was typing all this in mobile, so, I spotted mistakes. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I'm cloning your repo now. I'll let you know what I find.

Comment: Unable to help, my friend.  I'm on a Chromebook and setting up MongoDB is somewhat difficult.  If you can convert it to Postgres for the time being, I could most certainly help seeing as this is not a DB issue.

Comment: Can you sign up in some cloud VM like Nitrous? That removes a lot of problems and uses Linux as well too. I use it 99% of the time of the workflow.